# Label a set of numbers with an easily comparable "reference number".

Tags: combinatorics

I have a set of numbers (product codes).

I want to perform some calculation that returns a short easily compared "reference number" to identify this set.

Each week, I compare the records in my database with my packing slips used to ship goods.

So my database will record that a shipment with the following product codes was shipped.

32600,32600,12589,13872,14899,16990,34907,5003,42988

If everything has been performed correctly, I expect the packing slip to record the same information.

It is a very tedious task to do this sort of comparison.

Is there a function I can perform on this set that will return a simple, easy to compare number.

For instance, the set above might return 986547. A number calculated to be unique to this set. So all I would need to do is ensure the 986547 appears both in the database and on the packing slip.

As I'm sure you can tell from the style of question, I'm not great at Maths. But I know enough to ask the question here!

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [cyclic redundancy check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) or a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).  Either one will take a list of numbers and return a single value, which you can compare for the two lists.  You will need to sort the numbers in the list or the output values will disagree.  You need a small version or the length of your output number may be greater that the input numbers an it won't save any work.

Comment: For OP's purposes, it might be feasible to use a very simple hashing function, perhaps something as simple as adding the product codes and discarding all but the last 5 digits.

Comment: @MJD:  That is a good idea.  It will catch number replacements, single digit errors and single transpositions, which are probably the most common errors.